# Linux VM on windows host is faster than host machine

Tags: virtual-machine

I have installed OpenSUSE linux as VM in Windows7 as Host machine. What I am not able to understand is, why same operation in linux VM is running faster than in Windows7. 
For example : If I am building my set of files which includes downloading dependency files from the different network, surprisingly Linux VM is taking less than half the time taken by Windows 7 host machine.

Shouldn't it be the case that all the I/O operations and network operations are to be governed by the Windows7(host) machine. So be it build or deploy, storing or copying the files, Linux VM should be dependent on windows machine and hence should be slower.

But what I experience is totally opposite, I find that VM is much faster in all sense. Could someone explain me a reason why VM is running faster than the host machine.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I also tried installing VM without setting virtualization from BIOS, and found it much slower than after setting through BIOS.

Answer (score 2):

Virtual machines aren't the laggards they used to be.

A lot of the stuff, though virtualised, is done so at a very low level, hence fast.

For example, the CPU itself can now provides a large amount of the virtualisation without too much involvement by the host operating system.

And the VM file system is simply a gateway through to a single file (or few files) on the host, there's not much extra management required there.

So it doesn't surprise me at all that an operating system in a virtual machine could run as fast or faster than the host itself, provided the OS actually *is* faster. Whether that's actually the case for Linux v. Windows, I won't get into that argument.